# Bash grep regex issue with two different files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I have the following command which is filtering 3-letters words from a file made of upper case words only - one word per line:

```
grep -E '^[A-Z]{3}$' test
```

The command returns a correct list of words when used with a file `test` containing 10 words. When applied to a much bigger file `dico.txt` containing over 30,000 words, the command does not return anything (a new prompt is simply displayed).

As I thought it might be either an extension or a file size issue, I've tried:

- `cp test test.txt` to match the big file `*.txt` extension
- Create a new file `dico_small.txt` selecting 1000 lines from `dico.txt`

...both without success.

Comment: Are you sure the large file contains any 3-letter uppercase words?

Comment: Yes indeed! I also tried with other figures (5, 6, 7, etc.) but same behaviour...

Comment: Could it be that the large file has windows line endings `\r\n` instead of linux line endings `\n`? In that case, the `\r` before the `\n` would prevent `grep` from matching anything since your regex demands a letter directly before `\n`. What is the output of `file youLargeFile`?

Comment: output: `dico.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: @wiltomap Just as I thought. `CRLF` means *carriage return `\r`, line feed `\n`*. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367400/6770384) for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your large file has windows line endings, that is `\r\n` instead of linux line endings `\n`.

`\r` is called *carriage return* and is treated as a normal character by `grep`. When you write `grep -E "a$" fileWithWindowsLineEndings` then `grep` won't find anything because in front of the linux line ending `\n` (denoted as `$` in grep) there is always a `\r` and never an `a`.

You can convert your file to a normal linux file by deleting all `\r` characters.

```
tr -d '\r' < fileWithWindowsLineEndings > fileWithLinuxLineEndings
grep -E '...' fileWithLinuxLineEndings
```

Alternatively, convert the file on the fly without saving the conversion result:

```
tr -d '\r' < fileWithWindowsLineEndings | grep -E '...'
```